# Return single int to ajax/json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery script that makes an ajax post with some data to an MVC controller.

The controller action does some work and I end up with a single int (total). I want to be able to pass that single value back to the ajax call in the success section and use it...

The problem is I don't know the correct `return x` to use in the mvc controller and /or how to access it in jQuery.

The ways I have tried all return an object `{ Total : 123 }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You say you're hitting "a controller action with some parameters to return an int." -- so the controller returns an integer and you're trying to get access to the that value? Or are you trying to pass the integer to the controller? And you're saying that `{ json }` creates and object, but you just want the value `json`, but it's not clear to me how you *don't already* have that value (i.e., inside `json`)...? It may also help the say what framework you're using here -- what is the `Json` function here?

Comment: If you want it as a int why converting it to an object? Why not just using return total; ?

Comment: In your ajax `success(data)` you should be able to do `var total = data.total`   or you could `return Content(total)` and forget putting it in json.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, have been trying to work it out from other posts.  I make an Ajax post to an mvc controller.  that does what it needs to do and the final result is a a single int variable.

In the ajax success I am struggling to work out how I can access that single variable or the correct way to pass it to the Ajax... it passes it back ans an obect {Total : 123 }

Comment: I agree with @freedomn-m, `retut data.total` in success callback function avoid to return an object

Comment: thanks @freedom-m just that worked.

Answer (score 3):

In the MVC controller, you can return return plain "content" which returns what you specify exactly as-is, eg:

```
var total = 123;
return Content(total);
```

your calling code will get simply "123".

In the `$.ajax` call, you can access this such as

```
success: function(data) { var total = data; }
```

---

Alternatively, you can return from the controller as a Json object, eg

```
return Json(new { Total = total });
```

and access that via a property:

```
success: function(data) { var total = data.Total; }
```

note that it is case-sensitive (hence `Total =` matches `data.Total`)

Comment: return Json(new { Total: total }); should be return Json(new { Total = total });

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string version of a JavaScript object, do as follows.  It works with associated arrays as well as arrays.  I would recommend the former as, when you read the text later, it will be a lot easier to work with.

Just a heads up, this uses only JavaScript (no need to put in any jQuery, here).

```
<script>

associatedArray = {
    "scrore":55
};

array = [55];

console.log(JSON.stringify(associatedArray));

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

</script>
```